# proof of optimal path in a triangle ABC

Tags: geometry

I'm having a hard time proving this problem.

"Given a triangle ABC, call a hub point H a trisection point if the three angles formed by AH, BH, and CH are equal. For a triangle with no angle greater than 120◦, show that the network with a trisecting hub gives a strictly shorter total length than the shortest path along the edges."

I get stuck at the part where I need to show that the lengths of the three lines extending from H to each vertex are shorter than the perimeter of the triangle.

Comment: thanks Hagen, i have looked over my notes and confused this with the case of an equilateral triangle. my question has been reworded to make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H$ is at the origin of our coordinate system and $A$ at $(1,0)$, then $B$ is at $(-u,u\sqrt 3)$ and $C$ at $(-v,-a\sqrt 3)$ for some positive $u,v$.
The length of $AB$ is given by  $$|AB|^2=(1+u)^2+(u\sqrt3)^2=1+2u+4u^2=\frac34+\left(\frac12+2u\right)^2$$
so that 
$$ |AB|>2u+\frac12$$

Likewise,
$$ |AC|>2v+\frac12.$$
On the other hand,
$$ |HA|=1,\qquad |HB|^2=u^2+3u^2=4u^2,\qquad |HC|^2=4v^2.$$
We conclude
$$ |HA|+|HB|+|HC|=2u+2v+1<|AB|+|AC|$$

Comment: Thank you Hagen. This solutions seems practical and straight to the point. If anybody has a different solution, then I am all ears. For now,  I will accept Hagen's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Consider triangle HBC. Since $\angle BHC = 120^0$, we can say that BC must be the longest. In particular, BC is longer than HC. Similarly, ....

Comment: Thanks for your response Mick. Your solution is good, but unfortunately the question does not allow me assume that I have an equilateral triangle. I get what you're saying though. Any more solutions are appreciated.

Comment: My answer depends only on H is a trisection point. There is no equilateral triangle at all.

Comment: If the three angles formed by AH, BH, and CH are equal, then each of these angles is equal to $120^0$, by "angles at a point".

Comment: I reread your answer and I see that you are correct. 360÷3=120. Thank you. Any other solutions still welcomed.

Comment: @ManuelQuiroz Answers that are correct and acceptable to you, you should have them upvoted.